# Problemas con configurar mod_rewrite para OJS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo una instalación de OJS, con la configuración que permite eliminar el index.php de la dirección. Mi Apachees is 2.4 y mi htaccess es como sigue:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

El log que recibo es el siguiente:

```
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678593 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678834 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/revista -> index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678852 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678936 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678957 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678975 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.678990 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d4640a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679134 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679157 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679222 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679268 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679289 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679306 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679320 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d467ce0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679425 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679447 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679460 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679485 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679501 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679518 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679567 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d43b738/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679666 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679688 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679702 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679734 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679750 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679766 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679781 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d463208/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679881 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679926 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679962 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.679989 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680006 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680023 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680038 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d468028/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680179 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680209 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680225 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680252 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680282 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680311 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680327 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d45aec8/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680425 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680457 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680475 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680502 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680518 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680535 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680669 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d46e028/initial/redir#6] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680788 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680810 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680824 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680851 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680868 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680894 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.680911 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d458278/initial/redir#7] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681008 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681029 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681073 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681115 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista' -> 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista'
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681133 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681152 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista -> /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681168 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d457590/initial/redir#8] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jun 27 12:09:27.681278 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 16875] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 191.125.13.192:52458] 173.212.228.230 - - [summapsico.s4e.cl/sid#7f846c964328][rid#7f846d452c88/initial/redir#9] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php -> /var/www/vhosts/summapsico.s4e.cl/httpdocs/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/revista
```

Lo que debería suceder es que si alguien coloca
https://summapsico.s4e.cl/revista
debería poder mostrar:
https://summapsico.s4e.cl/index.php/revista

Comment: tu pregunta se encuentra en inglés, y el sitio es en español, por favor tradúcela para que no te cierren tu pregunta.

Comment: Y luego de traducirlo, por favor explica con tus palabras cómo debería reescribir, dando ejemplos de URLs con el resultado esperado, junto a casos que no deberían reescribirse